# Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location now throws ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: .net, node.js, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

In a node.js native addon in Visual Studio 2010 (and .Net 4) I could use

```
System::Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location
```

to get the path of the running C++/CLI assembly, but in a node.js addon in Visual Studio 2015 project (and .Net 4.6), I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(
      String[] str)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(
      FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control,
      String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates,
      Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(
      FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_Location()
```

Any idea how to get the path of the running assembly?

**Edit 2018-01-25**
This is still not resolved with Visual Studio 2017, this time trying .Net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `Location` property throws, `CodeBase` can still be used, which returns something like:

```
file://?/C:/.../my-addon.node
```

And that would explain the illegal character: The '?'

A `new Uri(Application.CodeBase).LocalPath` will return

```
/?/C:/.../my-addon.node
```

so a workaround for `GetExecutingAssembly()->Location` could be:

```
String^ GetExecutingAssemblyLocation()
{
  try
  {
    return Path::GetDirectoryName(Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location);
  }
  catch (Exception^ e)
  {
    String^ codeBase = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->CodeBase;
    if (codeBase->StartsWith("file://?/"))
    {
      Uri^ codeBaseUri = gcnew Uri("file://" + codeBase->Substring(8));
      return codeBaseUri->LocalPath;
    }
    else
      throw;
  }
}
```

which will return

```
C:\...\my-addon.node
```